# How to sort columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have three fields in each row and I want to concatenate them, sorted ascending:

```
select * concat(field1, field2, field3) AS result
from tbl
```

My data is:

```
field1, field2, field3
   7       2       9
   4       7       8
   6       3       2
```

The expected result is:

```
field1, field2, field3   result
  7       2       9       279
  4       7       8       478
  6       3       2       236
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have always the same number of fields ?

Comment: @amd no they are different and always they may change the number , I want concat them from lower value to high

Comment: Will your fields contain only single digit number?

Comment: @amd yes just the number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEAST` ,`GREATEST` function technically

```
   SELECT field1, field2, field3,
   concat(LEAST(field1,field2,field3), 
   (field1 + field2 + field3) - (GREATEST(field1,field2,field3)+
   LEAST(field1,field2,field3)),
   GREATEST(field1,field2,field3)
   ) 
   from tbl
```

Comment: @mohammad zahedi does it helps?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) approach. It can be extended to any number of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE testdata(id INT PRIMARY KEY, field1 INT, field2 INT, field3 INT);
INSERT INTO testdata (id, field1, field2, field3) VALUES
(1, 7, 2, 9),
(2, 4, 7, 8),
(3, 6, 3, 2);

SELECT testdata.id, field1, field2, field3, GROUP_CONCAT(rtc.fields ORDER BY fields SEPARATOR '') AS fields_sorted
FROM testdata
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, field1 AS fields FROM testdata UNION ALL
    SELECT id, field2 AS fields FROM testdata UNION ALL
    SELECT id, field3 AS fields FROM testdata
) AS rtc ON testdata.id = rtc.id
GROUP BY testdata.id, field1, field2, field3;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------------+
| id | field1 | field2 | field3 | fields_sorted |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------------+
|  1 |      7 |      2 |      9 | 279           |
|  2 |      4 |      7 |      8 | 478           |
|  3 |      6 |      3 |      2 | 236           |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution, though I haven't tested it. You will be able to achieve what you want by doing slight tinkering.  Any improvements, do mention in comments.

```
select id, concat(MIN_VAL, MIDDLE_VAL, MAX_VAL) 
from
   ( SELECT ID,
        (CASE
            WHEN field1 >= field2 AND field1 >= field3 THEN field1
            WHEN field2 >= field1 AND field2 >= field3 THEN field2 
            WHEN field3 >= field1 AND field3 >= field2 THEN field3
            ELSE  field1 END) MAX_VAL

    ,Case When field1 < field2 And field1 < field3 Then field1 
                When field2 < field1 And field2 < field3 Then field2 
                Else field3
                End As MIN_VAL
    ,Case When (field1 >= field2 And field1 <= field3) OR  (field1 <= field2 And field1 >= field3) Then field1 
                When (field2 >= field3 And field2 <= field1) OR (field2 <= field3 And field2 >= field1)Then field2
                 WHEN (field3 >= field1 AND field3 <= field2) OR  (field3 <= field1 AND field3 >= field2) THEN field3 
                Else field1
                End As MIDDLE_VAL

       From table
) int_pass
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution is to benefit from the native `json_extract` function to extract the values in a ascending order according to their keys.

---

```
select json_extract('{"10":10, "5": 5}', '$.*'); // [5, 10]
```

1. build the json object using `json_object` function, and use the same field for both the key and the value
2. extract the values in the desired order using `json_extract`
3. replace the `[`, `,` and `]` with empty spaces

---

```
select json_extract( json_object(f1, f1, f2, f2, f3, f3), '$.*' )
```

assuming `f1 = 5, f2 = 4 and f3 = 1`, you get `[1,4,5]`

now you can replace the unneeded characters using the replace characters

```
select replace( replace( replace( json_extract( json_object(f1, f1, f2, f2, f3, f3), '$.*' ), '[', ''), ']', ''), ', ', '') from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** that you want forth column as string concatenation in order field2, field1, field3

Try :

```
select * ,concat(field2,field1,field3) as "result" from tbl;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is my answer , becuase the value of number always change and diffrent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function of MySQL as:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(field1, field2, field3) AS result from tbl;
```

Comment: hi but my question is diffrent I want to order them from lower to upper value